# Google Map not displaying in my site

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to implement a google map in my site. According to the tutorial I have what is necessary including the Google API key. However the map is not showing up the page loading as it should. Help?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="map-container">
        <div id="map" class="map-box"></div>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map
            });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*******&callback=initMap"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.map-container {
    padding-left: 11%; 
    padding-right: 11%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.map-box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: you  should set a real size for map div eg: style='height: 400px; width: 400px;'

Comment: Tried that :/ still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
html,body { 
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a jsfiddle of the example working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/n8a84wh8/1/

JavaScript:

```
var map;
var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
var marker;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  }),
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: uluru,
     map: map
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id class="map-container">
  <div id="map" class="map-box"></div>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

CSS:

```
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.map-container {
    padding-left: 11%; 
    padding-right: 11%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.map-box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }
```